# nuxtjs issue with IE11 compatibility_ object assign

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer-11, compatibility, nuxt.js, babel-polyfill

I am suffered by IE compatibility. (my vue version is 3.1.0, nuxt is 2.3.4)

It keeps error with `Object.assign`. Here is the list what I have tried.

- babel-preset-vue-app(https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-vue-app). Heard that it does not support vue2.X. I followed the description on [this post](https://cmty.app/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/c73). It gets an error while building source.
- Adding babel-polyfill in `nuxt.config.js`. It does not error, but still I got Object.assign error on the page.
- Install `babel/plugin-transform-object-assign`. It also does not make any error in build process, but got Object assign thing in the page.

Is there any option I can try to feet IE11 compatibility?

Here is my current `.babelrc` and `nuxt.config.js`.

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "env",
            {
                "modules": false
            }
        ],
        [ "vue-app",
            {
                "useBuiltIns": true,
                "targets": {
                    "ie": 9,
                    "uglify": true
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign",
        "transform-vue-jsx",
        [
            "module-resolver",
            {
                "root": [
                    "./src"
                ],
                "alias": {
                    "~sbdc": "./src/sbdc"
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

build option in nuxt.config.js

```
build: {
    babel: {
        presets: [
            ['vue-app', {
                useBuiltIns: true,
                targets: { ie: 9, uglify: true }
            }
            ]
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',                  
            maxInitialRequests: Infinity,       
            minSize: 0,                     
            cacheGroups: {              
              vendor: {
                  test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](babel-polyfill|moment|lodash|axios|get-size|jquery|js-cookie|jwt-decode|numeral|vuetify)[\\/]/,
                  name: 'utilityVendor'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: serviceConfig.pwa_publicPath || false
    },
    extractCSS: true,
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin( {
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        } )
    ]
}
```

Thanks for sharing you solutions!

======= Edited in 0114 =============

Etra information #1.
When I look at the error on ie11 browser, it automatically transform code like below

```
return {layout:"popup",data:[{resultBody:Object.assign(Object.create(null), ... sorry, sensitive data
```

while the original code is...

```
asyncData: async function ({req}) {
    return {
        resultBody: req.body,
    };
},
```

`req.body` is supported by `body-parser`.

Comment: Is req.body a plain js object? If no - better to make it pojo and it will work.
Or you can add https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default%2CObject.assign
or you can object assign polyfill yourself as js https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @Aldarund Thanks for the advice. However(no offense, but in pure curiosity), I do not get it why should use polyfill.io, since in my opinion, babel-polyfill is already provided. To me, babel encourage to use `babel-*`(In case of `Object.assign`, https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-assign). Thanks for your answer again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of struggling, I solved this with not good way(In my thought).

I just add [object-assign polyfill js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to nuxt.js

```
module.exports = {

    ...

    head: {
        script: [ { src: '/js/object-assign.js' } ]
    },

    ... 

};
```

But I still want to know the proper way to apply babel-polyfill into nuxt project.

Comment: From your last post, I can see that you had solved your issue. I suggest you to mark that post as an accepted answer for this question after 24 hrs may help other community members in future in similar kind of question. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I got the point. I will accept after 24 hours later, but the solution seems not clean enough in my perspective. There are several babel presets(`@vue/babel-preset-app`, `@nuxt/babel-preset-app`, `@nuxtjs/babel-preset-app` ) in npm repository and there is no rules to use which of them. (also how to apply does not clear)